# pandas concat two column values which do not have headers

Tags: python, pandas

Attached is the data file.

In the **Department** column (column 4), the last column, there are values that have been split into additional columns. The data should only have 4 columns.

**How can I join the data in columns 4 and up via Pandas?**

[CSV RAW DATA FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNxx1.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix could be to name columns 5 and 6 and then address the value via `column4 + column5 + column6`.